# Creating new table, incorrect syntax error

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have created a new database in a SQL Server and I am trying to create a new table using the following query.

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders (
    CONSTRAINT order_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
    OrderNumber nvarchar(100),
    LoadLoaded nvarchar(100),
    LoadRequiredDate nvarchar(100)
    );
```

After running the query I receive the error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
> Incorrect syntax near 'OrderNumber'.

I have tried putting the column name within square brackets but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to specify the `id` column in the statement in which you create the `orders` table.  Try doing something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE orders ( 
  id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
  OrderNumber nvarchar(100), 
  LoadLoaded nvarchar(100), 
  LoadRequiredDate nvarchar(100),
  CONSTRAINT order_pk PRIMARY KEY (id) );
```